# How to open a text file and read the contents from it on react native?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, filesystems, text-files, expo

I want to read and display the text contents from a .txt file which is saved locally to the app build with react native.

The text is huge hence i cant hard code it to the code.

Comment: Do you have the option of putting it in a `json` file? Then you could import it like you are used to. `const hugeText = require('./my-huge-text.json').text;`

Comment: @Tholle No there's no option to put them to json file . Have to work it out with reading them as text file(.txt).

Comment: I see, that's unfortunate. I'm not sure it's even possible to import a `txt` file in React Native.

Comment: Use `XMLHttpRequest` to read file: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446447/how-to-read-a-local-text-file

Comment: @CrazyVK I dont think that'll work with ReactNative

Answer (score 3):

I think you are using Expo,

You can use expo filesystem https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/filesystem

Which is a native wrapper for platform specific system file management methods. You can read and change files managed in your app's domain.

For Eg:

`Expo.FileSystem.readAsStringAsync(fileUri)`